# For a familiar, do the skill ranks you get from a headband of vast intellect count as the master's skill ranks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars, skills

I understand most of the rules about a familiars skills but a friend asked about  something i hadn't thought of. The skill ranks you get from a headband of vast intellect, do those ranks count as the "Master's skill ranks"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes, they do

From the PFSRD entry for the [*headband of vast intelligence*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/h-l/headband-of-vast-intelligence):

> the headband grants a number of skill ranks in those skills equal to the wearer’s total Hit Dice.

Note that they are skill ranks, not just a bonus of some sort. So, yes, they would work for a familiar, or any other effect examining the skill ranks possessed by the caster.